# Laravel eloquent complex search query question

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, relationship

Have been trying different approaches to perform a search query with Eloquent on multiple and nested many-to-many and hasmany relationships but having trouble finding the solution.

To simplify below the part of the models where I want to perform the search using `'model', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%'`.

**The models**

```php
    class Company extends Model {
        // the class properties, dates, etc...
        public function offices(){
            return $this belongsToMany(Office::class);
        }
    }

    class Office extends Model {
        // the class properties, dates, etc...
        public function companies(){
            return $this belongsToMany(Company::class);
        }

        public function addresses(){
            return $this belongsToMany(Address::class);
        }
    }

    class Address extends Model {
        // the class properties, dates, etc...
        public function offices(){
            return $this belongsToMany(Office::class);
        }

        public function services(){
            return $this belongsToMany(Service::class);
        }

        public function countries(){
            return $this belongsToMany(Country::class);
        }
    }

    class Service extends Model {
        // the class properties, dates, etc...
        public function addresses(){
            return $this belongsToMany(Address::class);
        }
    }

    class Country extends Model {
        // the class properties, dates, etc...
        public function addresses(){
            return $this belongsToMany(Address::class);
        }
    }
```

The goal to to search on the different models based on the main model which is **Company**. In pseudo code would be something like the following:

- Find in **Company** where **name** like `$request->name`
- Or where **Company** **website** like `$request->name`
- Or where **Office** **office_name** `$request->name`
- Or where **Address** **street** `$request->name`
- Or where **Address** **country.name** `$request->name`
- Or where **Service** **addresses.service.name** `$request->name`

A **Company** has many **Office**
An **Office** has many **Address**
An **Address** has a **Country** and
An **Address** has many **Services**.

In all of them, and to simplify (i'll probably be able to extrapolate and work o other fields for each model, I'll be using the **name** column. Eg. *company name*, *office name*, *address name*, *service name* *country name*.

What I have now is the following which is not performing the search as I need:

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $data = Company::Active()->with('offices', 'addresses', 'offices.addresses')
        ->where('company_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->orWhere('company_short_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->orWhere('company_long_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->orWhere('company_website', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->whereHas('offices', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%');
        })
        ->whereHas('offices.addresses', function ($query) use($request){
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
                ->orWhere('address_city', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%');
        })
        ->orderBy('company_name')
        ->paginate(20);

    return response()->json($data, 200);
}

Thank you in advance for any help or tips on the better solution to perform this broad (complex) search query with Eloquent.
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Comment: I like this approach myself, it includes nested relations. https://freek.dev/1182-searching-models-using-a-where-like-query-in-laravel Makes it very clean imo

Comment: Is this search function used for a jquery datatable by any chance? If so, you could just define searchable attributes in your view and let the datatable handle the rest. If not, maybe you could just filter **after** making the query by using collection methods such as `filter()`

Comment: @IGP no datatables. That would be easier. Even a rway query would be easier for me but in Eloquent I get kind of confused with queries of this type on nested relationships. Company > Office > Address > Country + Services. In a raw Mysql I know how to do it straight away. Will take a look at dparoli and Robbin Bernard suggestions also.

Comment: Tried the suggestions with the macros but no success. Some errors for the method `orWhereHas()`. Still stuck... but meanwhile I'll keep trying to reach a solution.

Comment: I might be able to convert the raw sql query to eloquent/builder format if you edit it in your question.

Comment: Thank you anyway @IGP but I think that with the below query I have it. My only question there was if it could be optimized but not even something important. The result set gives me back the data I need. But thank you again for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could manage the query. Not sure if the best approach or it might need some optimization, but I could get at least the most approximate result sets from the below query. Suggestions on improvements are welcome :)

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $data = Company::Active()->with('offices', 'addresses', 'offices.addresses')
        ->where('company_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->orWhere('company_short_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->orWhere('company_long_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->orWhere('company_website', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
        ->orWhereHas('offices', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('offices.addresses', function ($query) use($request){
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%')
                ->orWhere('address_city', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('offices.addresses.services', function ($query) use($request){
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->name . '%');
        })
        ->orderBy('company_name')
        ->paginate(20);

    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```